# Finding child Id present for particular parent id - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the below two TR HTML DOM tree. I have to find the total count of id `necessary` is mapped only for id `successDesktop`.

```
<TR class="greybgContent" id="7">
    <TD align="center">
        <DIV class="necessary" id="necessary">&nbsp;</DIV>
        &nbsp;
    </TD> 
    <TD>8 Bureau Consent </TD>
    <TD id="successDesktop">
        <DIV class="floatLeft selectWidth15">
            <DIV class="available"></DIV>
        </DIV>
        <DIV class="floatLeft selectWidth85 greenText">Uploaded</DIV>
    </TD>
</TR>
<TR class="greybgContent" id="8">
    <TD align="center">
        <DIV class="necessary" id="notrequired">&nbsp;</DIV>
        &nbsp;
    </TD> 
    <TD> 9 Address Details</TD>
    <TD id="successDesktop">
        <DIV class="floatLeft selectWidth15">
            <DIV class="available"></DIV>
        </DIV>
        <DIV class="floatLeft selectWidth85 greenText">Uploaded</DIV>
    </TD>
</TR>
```

Comment: It is invalid HTML to have multiple elements with the same ID. Besides that I have no clue what you are saying.

Comment: @trincot The ids are different as it is populated based on if else condition

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I believe this may be what you are trying to accomplish (I used jQuery).

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // set the initial count to zero
    var count = 0;

    // loop over all table rows
    $('tr').each(function(index, obj){

    // try to find an element with the id 'successDesktop'
    if ($(obj).find('#successDesktop').length > 0) 
    {
      // if 'successDesktop' exists, look for an element with id 'necessary'
      if ($(obj).find('#necessary').length > 0)
      {
         // increase the count
         count++;
      }
    }
  });
  console.log('count: ', count);

});
```

Additionally you may want to use classes instead of IDs for 'necessary' and 'successDesktop', because IDs are only intended to be used once per page. Classes are intended to be re-usable.